# Basic PHP concepts (accessing/declaring array variables)

Tags: php, arrays

```
$result = array();

for ( $i = 10; $i < 101; $i = $i + 10 ){
    $result[] = $i;
}
echo implode(", ", $result);
```

Hello...I'm new to PHP, and this really confused me, declaring a variable array even the code will work without it.

I've found this code here in the forum, regarding the removal of the comma in a for loop. I was wondering what variable is called when it is echoed? Is it the `$result = array()` or the `$result[]`? I've tried to remove the `$result = array();` and the code still work, is that mean, is it ok to just remove the `$result = array();`? Does it have some coding issues if it is removed?

Comment: just always remember, always initialize

Comment: When you declare an array, you can use empty brackets to push a new item into the array. `$foo = array(); $foo[] = 1;` is the same as `$foo = array(1);`. In PHP, you can simultaneously *create an array* and *add an item to it* by doing `$some_new_array[] = 'apples';` but I advise against this – be explicit and clear in your code.

Comment: You can do something like `$string = implode(", ", $result); `. It's good practice to define variables before you use them, but the code will still work without `$result = array();`.

Comment: welcome to php, it accepts lazy programming standards

Answer (score 0):

The line `$result = array();` is used to declare an array.

It's a better approach to use this especially when you have some other previously specified variable `$result` storing some other value. Mentioning this first line will reset any previously assigned value to `$result` and declare it as an array datatype.

`$result[] = $i;` means the value of $i keeps apppending to `$result` every time.